# Draw only biggest connected subgraph in graph-tool

Tags: python-3.x, graph-tool

In graph-tool, is there a way to only draw the biggest connected subgraph? I'm currently having one big connected subgraph and a few smaller connected subgraphs I'm not particularly interested in. I'm not sure how to find the subgraphs before drawing them, so I would be interested if there is a method provided by graph_tool.

If it helps, this is the source: https://github.com/jvdheyden/DBS/blob/master/projekt/phase3/main.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter out the largest component using `GraphView` and then draw it.

```
import graph_tool.all as gt

# Load a disconnected graph
g = gt.collection.data["netscience"]

# Extract the largest component
largest_comp = gt.GraphView(g, vfilt = gt.label_largest_component(g))

# Draw the largest component
gt.graph_draw(largest_comp, output = "largest_comp.svg")
```

This way, you don't lose the whole graph in case you need it after drawing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for directed networks, or at least for directed networks that are not strongly connected

Comment: @scrps93 : You can always set the graph undirected in graph-tool temporarily, and then get the largest component to draw it. Technically, it will be a Largest Weakly Connected Component.